# My SQL code does not pull up the data in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT teamName, Count(rank) AS totalRank
FROM Teams
GROUP BY teamName
HAVING COUNT(rank) >= 20
ORDER BY Count(rank) DESC;
```

I am trying to organize the database by organizing the rank greater than or equal to 20 in Descending order but when I run the program it does not pull any data. I know it is a problem with the code and not the database

Comment: What is your table definition?  What data is in the table?  What results does the query return?  What results did you expect?  Why?

Comment: is your database connection ok?? Give table definition.

Comment: Do you really have multiple teams with the same name in your `teams` table?  Your current query is counting the number of times each `teamname` appears in the table.

Comment: Maybe you want `SUM(rank)`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need aggregation. Just a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT teamName, rank 
FROM Teams
WHERE rank >= 20
ORDER BY rank DESC;
```